# Comparing algebraic and analytic spaces through the universal property of classifying topoi

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, categorical-logic, gaga

$\newcommand\kAlg{k\mathrm{Alg}}\DeclareMathOperator\Zar{Zar}\newcommand\Mnf{\mathrm{Mnf}}$I apologize beforehand if my question is naïve. I must admit that I do not know much about analytic/smooth geometry. Here is a very long introduction, my question is below.

Let $k$ be a ring. We may equip the opposite of $\kAlg_\text{fp}$ with the Zarisiki topology, and the corresponding Grothendieck topos $\Zar(k)$ classifies local $k$-algebras. This means that given any Grothendieck topos $\mathcal E$ with a internally local $k$-algebra object $R$ in it, we get a geometric morphism $I: \mathcal E \to \Zar(k)$ whose inverse image part $I^\ast$ sends the universal model $\mathbb A_k$ in $\Zar(k)$ to $R$. The inverse image functor preserves geometric logic, and all geometric type constructors (this includes all colimits and finite limits, but unfortunately not exponential objects). The topos $\Zar(k)$ contains the category of $k$-schemes which are locally of finite type over $k$ as a full subcategory.

Dubuc has constructed various models for synthetic differential geometry as sheaf categories on (some full subcategory) of the opposite of the category of $C^\infty$-rings. A good reference for those constructions is the book [Moerdijk and Reyes - *Models for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-4143-8). Each of those topoi contains the category of real smooth manifolds $\Mnf$ as a full subcategory, and the embedding preserves transversal pullbakcs and has many other nice properties. Let me take the Dubuc topos $\mathcal G$ as an example (see [Chapter 11](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108553490.019) of Bunge, Gago, and San Luis - *Synthetic differential topology*). Each model, and in particular the Dubuc topos, contains an internal $C^\infty$-ring $R$. It is in fact the image of the smooth line $\mathbb R$ under the embedding $\Mnf\to \mathcal G$. This internal $C^\infty$-ring $R$ satisfies many nice properties, and in particular it is an internal local $\mathbb R$-algebra.

The universal property of the classifying topos $\Zar(\mathbb R)$ now immediatelly gives us a functor $\Zar(\mathbb R)\to \mathcal G$ which sends the algebraic line $\mathbb A_\mathbb R$ to the line $R$ in the dubuc topos $\mathcal G$. The functor $\Zar(\mathbb R)\to \mathcal G$ seems to be a good way to compare algebraic geometry with smooth real manifolds. For example, since it preserves colimits, it preserves gluing constructions and thus will send the real projective space $\mathbb P^n_\mathbb R$ to "the projective space" in $\mathcal G$, which does agree with the actual projective space in the full subcategory $\Mnf$. In the same way, since $\Zar(\mathbb R)\to \mathcal G$ preserves finite limits, also spaces which are cut out from $\mathbb A_\mathbb R^n$ by finitely many polynomial equations, and spaces which are glued from such, will be send to the geometrically correct space in $\mathcal G$.

**Question**: Is it possible to approach the GAGA theorem (i.e. the existence of an embedding from schemes locally of finite type over $\mathbb C$ to analytic spaces and the fully faithfulness of that functor on the subcategory of proper $\mathbb C$-schemes) this way? Can we for example embed the category of analytic spaces in a sheaf topos (via a functor of points approach), find an internal local $\mathbb C$-algebra in it and use the induced functor from $\Zar(\mathbb C)$ to analytify schemes which are locally of finite type over $\mathbb C$? Does such a treatment of the GAGA theorems already exist?

Comment: The GAGA theorem is not existence of an analytification functor.  The GAGA theorem is (roughly) the statement that the analytification functor is an equivalence from the category of proper complex schemes to the category of proper complex analytic spaces whose underlying reduced structure is the analytification of a proper complex scheme (there is a way to encode sheaf cohomology of coherent sheaves in terms of nonreduced structures).

Comment: I suggest the tag `reference-request`, since it seems you are asking for a reference.